# I am trying to automate my sun shade on my back porch with a Nema17 Stepper motor

Tags: arduino-uno, stepper-motor, home-automation

I am very new to Arduino (and fritzing so please excuse my poor layout).
I am trying to automate my patio sun shade, eventually it will incorporate a photocell but I wanted a proof of concept first with buttons. The first and last buttons represent limit switches and the middle button represents a toggle switch (which will eventually become the photocell).

An example of what I am trying to do is;
If the upper limit switch is active and I press the toggle button, the stepper runs until it hits the lower limit switch, if the lower limit switch is active and I press the toggle button then the stepper should run the other direction until it hits the upper limit switch.

I have serial prints to show what is happening, if I hold either of the "limit switches" then the serial monitor displays (rather spams) the corresponding print line, however the stepper motor is not moving how I would expect it to. I have to be holding a limit switch and holding the toggle for it to move in a direction, even then it only moves approximately 1 step per second. If I release the limit switch and continue to hold the toggle then the stepper steps one back and one forward for the duration that I depress the switch. The code I have is based off of someone attempting the same thing but with a DC motor, I tried to accommodate it to a stepper motor and am having trouble.
[image]

```
    // constants won't change. They're used here to set pin numbers:
const int uplimitPin = 9;     // pin number for upper limit switch
const int togglebuttonPin = 10;     // pin number for the toggle switch
const int downlimitPin = 11;     // pin number for the lower limit switch
const int dirPin =  2;      // direction pin for stepper
const int stepPin =  3;      // step pin for stepper

// variables will change:
boolean uplimitState = 0;         // variable for reading the status of the upper limit switch
boolean togglebuttonState = 0;         // variable for reading the toggle switch status
boolean downlimitState = 0;   // variable for reading the status of the lower limit switch


int shadePosition = 2;  // Tells progam what position the shade is in


/**
 *  setup inputs for switches and outs for motor pins
 *  serial begin to read the switches to test for errors
 */
void setup() {
    // initialize the stepper pins as outputs:
    pinMode(dirPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(stepPin, OUTPUT);
    // initialize the pushbutton pins as an inputs:
    pinMode(uplimitPin, INPUT);
    pinMode(togglebuttonPin, INPUT);
    pinMode(downlimitPin, INPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

/**
 * this function turns motor foward 
 */
void shadeDown() {
     // turn motor foward:
    digitalWrite(dirPin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(stepPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(1000);
    digitalWrite(stepPin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(1000);
}

/**
 * this function turns motor backwards
 */
void shadeUp() {
     // turn motor in other direction:
    digitalWrite(dirPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(stepPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(1000);
    digitalWrite(stepPin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(1000);  
}

/**
 * Stop the motor form moving
 */
void stopShade() {
  digitalWrite(stepPin, LOW);

}


/**
 * 
 */
void loop() {
   // read the state of the pushbutton value:
   uplimitState = digitalRead(uplimitPin);
   togglebuttonState = digitalRead(togglebuttonPin);
   downlimitState = digitalRead(downlimitPin);



   // check if the limit is active. If it is, the limitState is HIGH:
   if (uplimitState == HIGH) {
      shadePosition = 2; 
      Serial.println(F("The shade is up")); 
      stopShade();
   }else if (downlimitState == HIGH) {
      shadePosition = 1;
      Serial.println(F("The shade is down"));        
      stopShade();
  } 

  if (togglebuttonState == HIGH) {
    if( shadePosition  == 1 ){
      shadeUp(); 
      delay(100);      
      shadePosition = 2;
      delay(100);  
    }else if (shadePosition == 2 ) {
      delay(100); 
      shadeDown();
      delay(100); 
      shadePosition = 1;       
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## System State Machine

As JRobert suggested, a state machine would make the code a lot cleaner! Below is some pseudocode (I'll leave the debugging up to you ;)) of how you might set that up.

When you break up your system into 4 distinct states, it's easy to reason about what should be happening at each state and what is required to get to the next state. You can draw a diagram showing this (google "state machine") to help you reason.

```
...

enum SystemState {
    SystemState_Opening,
    SystemState_Closing,
    SystemState_Open,
    SystemState_Closed
};

void main()
{
    // Set initial state
    SystemState state;
    if (digitalRead(upLimitState))
    {
        state = SystemState_Closed;
    }
    else
    {
        state = SystemState_Open;
    }

    // Run state machine
    while (1)
    {
        switch (state)
        {
            case SystemState_Closed:
            {
                if (digitalRead(toggleButtonPin))
                {
                    state = SystemState_Opening;
                }
                break;
            }
            case SystemState_Open:
            {
                // TODO: Implement this yourself!
                break;
            }
            case SystemState_Closing:
            {
                if (digitalRead(upLimitState))
                {
                    state = SystemState_Closed;
                }
                shadeUp();
                break;
            }
            case SystemState_Opening:
            {
                // TODO: Implement this yourself!
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

## What's Wrong With Your Code

The actual issue with the code you provided is that you're only calling the `shadeUp()` function once. You need to call it many times to send the step pin many pulses to rotate the motor.

Each time you send a pulse to the step pin (eg. `shadeUp()`), you rotate the motor by one step (or microstep) which is likely only 1.8 degrees!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're asking how debug the unexpected behavior your described (and not having any steppers on-hand to have a go at your code) I'll offer some observations and suggestions.

Pushbuttons "bounce" (not really, but their output signal looks like they bounce). For the limit switches, you won't really care - the first make (and I'm assuming positive logic, for simplicity of the discussion) tells you that the shade has reached it's limit, and you don't need to (probably shouldn't!) wait for the switch to settle before stopping the shade. The 'break' of a limit switch is uninteresting except possibly to confirm that the shade is moving when you expected it to, and again, who cares about the bounces? But the toggle button's bounces may well confound your logic unless you debounce it (can be done either electrically or in software - search the topic). And even though the eventual photocell may not bounce (or it may: are there shade-trees within it's view, f/ex?), right now, you're testing with a button which certainly does.

This is a would be a good application to implement as a state-machine, and even if you don't do that formally, diagramming a state-machine to operate your shade should make it clear what your code will need to do. If you're new to software as well as to Arduino, learning about state-machines might be a longer detour than you want to take at the moment, but if this kind of control system is what interests you, you will encounter them sooner or later, because they model your control system pretty directly, both graphically (because you usually sketch them out first) and in software.

State diagrams turn out to be one of the best tools a software designer has to communicate the details of a proposed control system between them and the typically-non-software-trained people who are the experts at building and/or using the devices being automated (think printing presses, copiers, assembly robots, .... ). The picture says it all.